# Infinite arithmetic progression and infitite geometric progression

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

An infinite arithmetic progression consisting only positive integers contains all members of an infinite increasing geometric progression except the first one and some other 2016 members. How to prove that the sum of these 2016 members is a multiple of 7?

Comment: Well, _have you tried anything_?

Comment: Yep, tried to prove that it will be the firste 2017 members, but failed, and if they're not the firste 2017s it's completely impossible to prove it